# Try this cake (out)

Tags: verbs

I was wondering if someone could tell me the difference between the following sentences:

> - Try this cake
> - Try this cake out

I guess the second sentence mean the same as the first one, but the second one is a bit informal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, these are very similar. To **try something out** means you are sampling it and judging its performance. Hence you can also say, **try someone out** (see how they do at a particular task).

For food, I don't think that you can use "out" though. Maybe officially you can, but in practice, this sounds very strange to me:

> Try this chicken **out**

For food, you should just use

> Try this chicken

On the other hand, if you're talking about a new restaurant, either version works

> We should try out the new Chinese place down the block!

OR

> We should try the new Chinese place down the block!

Answer (score 4):

When we "try something *out*", we *use* it to see if it works as it should or if it meets our expectations.

When we "try something" we sample it (eat a piece of it, take a go at it if it's an activity).

We might *try out* a cake *recipe*, but we would try the cake.

Complicating matters, if a speaker in his mind is thinking "cake recipe" (of if the conversation is about cake recipes) he might say:

> I'm going to try out this cake.

What he says is not exactly what he means.  By "this cake", he means making this cake according to some recipe.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends of context. For example *try this cake* just means *test this cake*.
*try this cake out* makes it a little bit different since you can try a cake to see whether you like it or want to buy it. For instance, *I tried this cake out before I bought it.* (But which place or who allow this? It's weird.)